# How to get a count of Distinct Dimension values in an SSAS MDX Query

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, distinct-values

I am trying to write an MDX query to return some information about survey questions.  I want Average response and total responses in my results.  I have two types of questions.  One type of question has a single response.  Another type of question can have multiple responses (Pick all that apply).  Each question is tied to a question ID and a respondent ID.  The following query works (somewhat)

```
Select NON EMPTY 
  {
    [Measures].[Average Response], [Measures].[Total Count]
  } ON 0
,   NON EMPTY 
  {
    ([Question].[Question ID].[Question ID].ALLMEMBERS)
  } ON 1
From [Cube]
```

Average Response is a combination from both single responses and multiple responses (two different fact tables).  The total count is also a combination of the two tables.  The problem is that for single response questions, I can just count the number of respondents.  For multi response questions that falls down as I can have way more responses than I do people taking the survey.  I really want to know how many people provided an answer.  To do this, I think I need the distinct count of respondent IDs.  So I tried changing my first axis to this.

```
[Measures].[Average Response], [Measures].[Total Count], DISTINCTCOUNT([Respondent].[Respondent ID])
```

Well, that doesn't work and I really didn't expect it to.  I got ***"The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 3 argument. A string or numeric expression was used."***  which is rapidly becoming my favorite SSAS error message.  I am still green at this and I guess I am still thinking SQL.  How can I get an average of the responses and a count of the distinct Dimension values in the same query.  BTW, my query does have a slicer and I could provide that if needed but I don't think it relevant as I get the same problems with or without the slicer.

Answer (score 0):

When working with the MDX `DistinctCount` function, it returns the count of distinct, non-empty tuples of a given set of data.  Perhaps try doing something like

`DistinctCount({[Respondent].[Respondent ID].members * [Measures].[Total Count]})`

so that way you are working with a set (e.g. `{...}`) of data.

If you're working with a larger set of data, you may want to consider creating a Distinct Count measure.  The `DistinctCount` function itself is a SSAS Formula Engine query while using the `Distinct Count measure` would allow Analysis Services to use both the Storage Engine and Formula Engine.  For more information, please refer to [Analysis Services Distinct Count Optimization](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=891).

Comment: I tried what you put and I get my favorite message _"The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used."_  Also, if I try to use it along with the average I get _"Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function."_  The frustrating part is I know exactly how to do this in SQL.

Comment: I can empathize - I am still pretty lousy at MDX myself and have been doing SSAS for years now ;-).  Saying this, when you run the `distinctcount` function, what  happens when you manually create a set, e.g. `with set myset as '{[Respondent].[Respondent ID].&[Q1], [Respondent].[Respondent ID].&[Q2], [Respondent].[Respondent ID].&[Q3]}'` (update the question members as appropriate) and see if you can get a response back?